# Initialize array from pointer and size of another array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy

In a function, I have access to the pointer and size of another array. Passing these along with the pointer, I want to add that data to a map. How can I do that without copying the underlying data twice?

```
void addToMap(double* ptr, size_t size, unsigned key) {

 // Here I want to add the array corresponding to the pointer location and size to the map.
 // Since adding to the map needs to copy the data once anyway, I want to prevent any other copies.
 double array[size] = ?;

 // Can I initialize this array from the data found at (ptr) to (ptr + size) without a copy?
 array& = ptr; 

 _map[key] = array;

}
```

The data being pointed to is deleted after this function is called. The map is just a map from an integer to an array of doubles. That simply means, I want to somehow store the data associated with this key while it is still available.

Or do you have a better idea of doing this? Would using a `std::vector<double>` slower here?

Comment: `double array[size]` isn't standard C++ anyways. Size of the array must be compile time constant.

Comment: Is using array necessary? Isn't simply using pointer like `double* array = ptr;` not accepted?

Comment: What is `_map` that you would try to assign to `_map[key]` by passing an array? You can't do what you are asking, but there may be other solutions depending on what `_map` is.

Comment: `array` in `_map[key] = array;` will automatically converted to a pointer anyway.

Comment: `std::vector<double> array(ptr, ptr + size);`.  That also means you map needs to have `std::vector<double>` as the value type

Comment: @NathanOliver It will copy the data, so it doesn't meed the condition "without copying".

Comment: @MikeCAT If `array` is a C array, that assignment *may* pass the array by reference. It will probably convert to pointer, but not necessarily. It depends on what `_map[key]` is.

Comment: it looks like you want c-arrays to be working in a way they don't. `_map[key] = array;` does not copy the array into the map

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, the condition is actually "without copying the underlying data twice", so copying once is allowed!

Comment: @MikeCAT That's how I read it.  OP, vector, when you have optimizations turned on, is just as fast as working with an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define an array variable like that because the function argument can vary at runtime, and is therefore not compile time constant which is a requirement for the size of an array variable.

You'll need to allocate the array dynamically. `std::vector` is the simplest way to do that.

An array can also not be directly initialised from a pointer to another array, whether you're initialising an array variable (which isn't an option here) or a dynamic array. Here too, `std::vector` helps with the constructors that it offers.

> How would I use `std::vector<double>` here then?

Example:

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::vector<double>> _map;

// addToMap
_map.emplace(key, std::vector<double>{ptr, ptr + size});
```

---

I recommend using `std::span<double>` as the argument instead of the pointer and size.

Comment: How would I use `std::vector<double>` here then?

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working. And this only copies the data once?

Comment: @EigenGrau Yes.

Comment: `I recommend using std::span<double> as the argument instead of the pointer and size.`

Why?

Comment: @EigenGrau It's simpler to use. That way you could for example call: `addToMap(some_array, key)` instead of `addToMap(some_array, std::size(some_array), key)`. Another alternative would be to accept a templated range by value which would allow avoiding a copy entirely if the caller passes an rvalue `std::vector<double>`.